# Update UI in Activity from Timer

Tags: android, android-activity, timer, timertask

I am developing an App of physical exercise. In my App I launch an Activity where it is displayed the exercise. When the exercise is finished, this Activity finishes and starts a new Activity to allow the user rest. When the rest is finished launches the Exercise Activity again. This process is repeated until the training time lasts more than the defined time by the user.

I need to update the UI of the Exercise Activity every second of my Timer.

I don't really know how to handle that approach with both activities sharing the same timer.

Comment: You need 2 CountDownTimers, one per Activity. On time up, one launches the other activity. They basically do the same thing.

Comment: You should not use Timer on Android, instead use Handler. There is even sample on https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html#MoveValues

Comment: "When the exercise is finished, this Activity finishes and starts a new Activity to allow the user rest" -- that is not an especially good approach IMHO. Use one activity. I have just gotten through evaluating some apps that do what you want. None seemed to use different activities for these phases. The [app that I chose](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slydroid.watch) definitely does not use separate activities. Whether you use fragments or other in-place UI updates is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend Android Activity class with your timer needs and extend your exercise classes from that one. Example:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import java.util.Timer;

public class MyTimedActivity extends Activity {
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    public Timer getTimer() {
        return timer;
    }

    public void setTimer(Timer timer) {
        this.timer = timer;
    }
}
```

Now, if your exercise classes extend from MyTimedActivity, you get a timer in each activity which is independant from the others.

Comment: Not really. You use **2** instances of the same class.

Comment: Yes, with two activities extending from MyTimedActivity, you have two independent timers. I edited my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: `you use only one timer` No, you are using **2** timers. **2** instances of a timer object. So, it's really **2** timers.

Comment: Ok thank you all for your help, finally I'm going to use 2 timers one for each Activity. I know this may not be the best approach to launch an Activity that launches other Activity but I want all the screen to be replaced so that's why I'm not using Fragments.